# Socat in Android

Tags: android, socat

I would like to use Socat for my android app. Has anyone ported Socat under Android? Could not find any useful links. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/CHANGES : V 1.7.2.0 : porting :
    Cedril Priscal ported socat to Android (using Googles cross compiler).
    The port includes the socat_buildscript_for_android.sh script

Answer (score 2):

FYI, socat for Android does not include support unix-socket connect. The build script has --disable-unix.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. And the workaround is to add `#include <sys/un.h>` to sysutils.h (and remove --disable-unix from the script).

Answer (score 1):

Some guy at XDA has compiled *socat* V2.0.0-b7 for Android [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=51837955&postcount=28). Works great.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: XDA linked pages doesn't change, unless the post is removed by moderators. All essential part/references of what was done to port it to android is also there.

Answer (score 0):

While it is not a true "port to Android" answer, I have been using socat on all of my Android-based devices for years by compiling a statically linked ARMv5 binary. The binary size is about 786K, but it gets the job done and can be used on any ARM-based Linux platform without regard to the C library in use.

Comment: Perhaps a download link?

Comment: It might not be up forever, but here you go: http://core.nctritech.com/do/socat-arm-static